# multiprocessing.Pool memory allocation error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am running script that is using multiprocessing Pooling on shared hosting. I am getting following error:

```
Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
(<type 'exceptions.OSError'>,
```

Below is my code:

```
with closing(Pool(processes=50)) as pool:
 csv_items = pool.map(get_stuff, list_ids)
 pool.terminate()
 pool.join()
```

Comment: That sure sounds like you're running out of memory. I'm not sure how much we can help with that. Perhaps try making your pool have fewer processes (it's usually not much benefit to have more than your CPU has cores).

Comment: @Blckknght Some sort of limitation by hosting provider because no such issue locally on my Mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you are trying to launch 50 more processes to be used by your pool. Now, this is not the same as threads, this will launch 50 new Python processes with all the python modules and libraries included.

By default, `Pool` will launch `cpu_count()` new processes, normally thinking in multicpu-multicores machines. Now every new Worker process will live by default for the complete duration of your Pool's work queue. If i will use a dedicated VPS instance i will go with precaution about create freely Worker Processes in my pool. In your case you are using a shared hosting and on this, the memory limitations will be bigger, showing the error message that you see above.

If you like to use this, then change your deployment from a shared hosting to a dedicated vps/cloud instance.

Comment: Thanks for reply, or reduce the # of processes to 2 or 3 only?

Comment: reduce to 2 or 3 ... and try, after this, increment one by one until the error launch again. If with 2 this fails, then your shared host limits all this and multiprocess python will not work, you will need to migrate to a dedicated vps.